# SSRS SQL Query display error after i add where clause

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a full query which can be display correctly in SSRS, however, when I add this `where` clause, I get an error

> Query execution failed for data set 'dataset1'. (rsErrorExecutingCommand)

This is the `WHERE` clause I add:

```
where 
    (itemNo = @ItemNo or @ItemNo is NULL) 
    and (JobNo in (@JobNo) or @JobNo is NULL) 
    and (customerNo = @CustomerNo or @CustomerNo is NULL) 
    and (LotNo in (@LotNo) or @LotNo is NULL)
    and (Station = @Station or @Station is NULL) 
    and ((DateTimeStamp between @startDate and  @endDate) or (@startDate is null and @endDate is Null))
```

Do you guys have any idea what is the syntax error I did here?

Comment: Perhaps the original query already had a `where` clause?

Comment: nope..this is the only where.i do suspect that the "in" is causing me trouble,since probably there are null value in the records.

Comment: Your parentheses balance.  I can imagine that the *logic* is wrong.  However, the only syntax issue (I think) would be a type incompatibility somewhere.

Comment: Can u explain on the 'incompatibility'?

Comment: If a column is one type (say an integer) and a variable is another type (say a varchar), then the comparison might fail because of a type incompatibility, when (if) the conversion fails.

Comment: Enable remote errors reporting as in MS docs http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337165.aspx then check the log -- This link should  help you locate the logs http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6bf2a4c9-f652-4c99-972b-75ba9d9447c2/locate-ssrs-log-files

Comment: your where clause will not work if \@startdate is null OR \@enddate is null ... you just check if they are both null

Comment: Thanks guys, I just check the query,and its working fine.the only problem is.when i run the filter,it didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

My codes is working after i add the String. below is what i did, and its working fine.
This is because,instead of Null, i notice the value is not Null, its a empty string,that is why my codes is not working.

```
(itemNo = @ItemNo or @ItemNo is NULL or @ItemNo = '') 
and(JobNo = @JobNo or @JobNo is NULL or @JobNo = '')
and(customerNo = @CustomerNo or @CustomerNo is NULL or @CustomerNo = '') 
and (LotNo = @LotNo or @LotNo is Null or @LotNo = '')
and (Station = @Station or @Station is NULL or Station = '') 
and ((DateTimeStamp between @startDate and @endDate) or (@startDate is null and @endDate is Null))
```